# How to create a loading cursor icon when ajax is called

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to have a loading cursor whenever an ajax request is called. However any other element the cursor is over will stop the cursor showing a loading icon. Adding !important didn't seem to make any difference either. How do you make the cursor load over every element hovered?

```
// cursor loading function
function start_request() {
$('body').css("cursor", "progress");
}

function end_request() {
$('body').css("cursor", "auto");
}


$('.new_filter_button').click(function(){ // when a feature button is selected
var serialize = $('#new_header_filters').serialize(); // takes all the values of the filter
$.ajax({
    beforeSend: start_request(),
    type : 'POST',
    url  : 'http://localhost/carprice/ajax/new-filters.php', 
    data : serialize,
    dataType : 'json',
    success : function(data) {
        $("#new_results_toolbar").html(data.toolbar);
        $("#new_results").html(data.models);
        retain_css();
        end_request();
    }
}); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your qeustion, I suggest you set up styles, with the !important, and then use those styles instead of adding the css inline. I've not tested this but believe it will work.

```
<style>
  .inProgress {
    cursor:progress!important;
  }
</style>
```

Then in your code just add and remove this:

```
function start_request() {
    $('body').addClass('inProgress');
}

function end_request() {
    $('body').removeClass('inProgress');
}
```

However, I suggest an alternative which would be to use a css plugin that will show a progress indicator for you and prevent the user from interacting by putting a div on top of everything. You can then include a pretty progress indicator.

Comment: no, thats what I am saying, even !important doesn't stop it.

Comment: What if I put an overlay over it all, and have that as the element that will load, with z-index:1000.

Comment: The !important will ensure this is applied to everything. If not, you need to use firebug to inspect an element to see what might be stopping your cursor from applying.

Comment: Yes, do use an overlay that is the standard practise. Here is a suggestion BlockUI: http://malsup.com/jquery/block/

Comment: will the overlay mean I can't click on any elements behind it?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The overlay would usually be a little transparent so you can still see what is under it.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to not only add and remove a "inProgress" class on the body tag, but also on every tag that has a cursor predefined. On my site, I have pointer cursors set for a tags and buttons throughout my site. So I am also adding and removing the inProgress class on all of those elements as well. You may need to also do it for images if any of those have a css style declaring what cursor is shown when you hover over them.